# is not a kind of ... as specified by the outlet type

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I'm using a derived UISearchBar because I have to set the font size:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SearchBar : UISearchBar
{
    UITextField *searchField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *searchField;

- (void) setFontSize: (NSInteger) size;

@end
```

In my ViewController the Outlet is defined:

```
@interface DictViewController : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView        *myTableView;
    IBOutlet SearchBar      *mySearchBar; 
    NSMutableArray *searchResults; 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SearchBar *mySearchBar;
...
```

InterfaceBuilder don't let me connect the SearchBar to mySearchBar.

If I change the outlet class to UISearchBar, IB let me connect to mySearchBar. When I change the class back to SearchBar, the connection remains, but with the warning "The 'mySearchBar' outlet of FilesOwner is connected to 'SearchBar' but 'UISearchBar' is not a kind of 'SearchBar' as specified by the outlet type"

What's wrong? Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

This might fix the problem.

In IB, select the search bar and go to the Identity pane of the inspector window. In the class dropbox, choose SearchBar instead of UISearchBar.